# jquery mobile tablet with high resolution

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, fonts, resolution

I have a program that I created using jQuery Mobile 1.3 (Awesome stuff), but I just ran into a problem yesterday after I purchased a windows 8 tablet with 1366x768 resolution. Everything is so small now.

Things I have tried

-Set the view port width 800px. (Works alright...on portrait but not landscape)
-Change the font size to 22pt (Looks ugly)
-I even tried to decrease the resolution on the tablet but only offers ahigher resolution in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the view port width to 800px works on portrait (like you said), then maybe you can use a CSS media query to set the view port width to something better in landscape.

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /*css goes here*/
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /*css goes here*/
}
```

Comment: brilliant! Let me give it a try. I feel so stupid, I tried to let jquery handle the responsiveness. LOL

Comment: you could use jQuery, but css is so much faster with that kind of thing that it tends to be more desirable to use css when possible.  Which is why css3 is so wonderful.